# What is the meaning of "Agrift"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I saw this word here today.
[A Party Agrift by Paul Krugman](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/13/opinion/a-party-agrift.html?smid=fb-nytopinion&smtyp=cur&_r=0)

What does "Agrift" here refer to?
I tried on Webster. I could find the meaning for "grift", which means "to acquire money or property illicitly". Still, not clear about "Agrift".

Comment: It's a pun. "Agrift" is a neologism combining the senses of *[being a**d**rift](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/adrift)* (undirected, purposeless, lost) and *[grift](http://onelook.com/?w=Grift&ls=a)* (corrupt, thieving, manipulative). The word is unused outside this pun.

Comment: @DanBron So, this means "A clueless corrupt"? Can I say it this way?

Comment: That's the right idea, but the expression "a [clueless] corrupt" is ungrammatical: *clueless* and *corrupt* are adjectives, and needs to modify something. Maybe "a clueless, corrupt [political] party".